# If IDs in HTML should be unique, why sometimes I see in Css see something like div#nav-blue?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Since an ID should be unique in HTML, why sometimes i see in Css selectors formatted like (div#nav-blue), since it's obvious that there will be no other element having this ID exccept for that div, so aint writting #nav-blue makes more sense?

Comment: Who knows? Could be someone who doesn't understand that IDs are meant to be unique, could be that the ID may be assigned to elements of different types on other pages and the author only wants to target it if it's assigned to a div on a given page, could be a specificity hack... or it could be entirely stylistic (for that author).

Comment: You cannot assume that #nav-blue will always be assigned to a div, for example. You can make such an assumption if you are in control of the markup and your rules say that it will only ever be assigned to a div, in which case yes div#nav-blue is redundant, but in another project the ID may be assignable to other element types - distinguishing the type may be useful to the author.

Comment: According to me, It doesn't makes any sense, uselessly adds into specificity of the selector. there are people who have habit of writing like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does no change or a little.

You can do this for some reason : more visibility when you maintain your code. Easier to find, and remember for each kind of element is the style.

The second reason is the priority of selector.

There is some different order of priority :

```
!important > #id > .class > element
```

you can consider that

```
 element = 1
 .class = 10
 #id = 100
 !important= 1000
```

And then `div#id` =  101 > `#id` = 100

```css
div#myid{
  color:red;
}

#myid{
  color:blue;
}

.myclass{
  color:yellow;
}

div{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass" id="myid">
Some text
</div>
```

Comment: Clear enough, Thank you very much.