# Cannot override previously defined css rule

Tags: html, css, layout, css-selectors

I have a simple table and associated CSS rules for the table as shown:
HTML:

```
<table id="depts">
            <tr>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Posts</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="none"> No Posts in this department</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#depts {
      width: 500px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      border-spacing: 0;
      border: 1px solid black;
  }
  #depts td{
      border-top: 2px solid #607D8B;      
      text-align: left;
      font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
      padding: 10px;
  }
  .none {
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 40px;
  }
```

As it can be seen, I've added a new class for a `td` named `none`.The text-align property has been changed from `left` to `center`.But it is not reflected, when I run the page.The output is as below:
[image: css class not working]

Why is'nt the new rule being ignored.Does `colspan` has anything to do with it?

Comment: Try adding a blank td element so your th and td element match up

Comment: try by using !important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `#depts` before your `.none` declaration.

`.none` class have a lower priority than `#depts td`.

You can take a look at priority order [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35696668/if-ids-in-html-should-be-unique-why-sometimes-i-see-in-css-see-something-like-d/35696904#35696904) or [here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

```css
#depts {
      width: 500px;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      border-spacing: 0;
      border: 1px solid black;
  }
  #depts td{
      border-top: 2px solid #607D8B;      
      text-align: left;
      font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
      padding: 10px;
  }
 #depts .none {
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 40px;
  }
```

```html
<table id="depts">
            <tr>
                <th>Department</th>
                <th>Posts</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="none"> No Posts in this department</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the "important"  flag to the none class like this:

```
.none {
      text-align: center!important;
      padding-top: 40px;
  }
```

Comment: Use `!important` to override an inline style you cannot modify. Otherwise, understand CSS specificity and avoid `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is *ignored* (not really ignored) because it has lower [specificity](https://specificity.keegan.st/) (See: [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)).

You could use:

```
#depts td.none {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ID has more priority than class so you can add

```
 #depts .none {
      text-align: center;
      padding-top: 40px;
  }
```

or

```
.none {
      text-align: center!important;
      padding-top: 40px;
  }
```

CSS Specificity can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)